# Register same username and email in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, email

I have a to do this http://jsfiddle.net/67BUG/2/ in wordpress registration, but I have tried and nothing works.

This is the code in wp-login.php - http://pastebin.com/CWFsrCPS, with the javascript code in the line 681.

The inputs is in the lines 693 and 697.

Here is the javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('.inputs').on('keyup',function(){
      $(this).parent().not(this).find('.inputs').val($(this).val());
    });
  });
</script>
```

Someone who can help me please?

Comment: What's the specific problem?

Comment: Look like you want to add some custom jQuery in WP registration page. The pastebin you posted seem like a WP core file, yes? Which one? The lines you mention **don't correspond to anything relevant**; ain't it lines `682` to `689`??. Please, [edit] and clarify your Question and read [ask] beforehand.

Comment: My code didn`t work in wp-login.php. I don't know if I wrote it correcttly inside the  wp-login.php code.

Comment: You added the jQuery commands in the jsfiddle code in `wp-login.php` and it didn't work? . . . Modifying that file is not the correct thing to do: you'll have to change it again at **every WP update**. But for testing purposes, it should work.

Comment: Note that all the relevant code should be posted **here**, external links to jsfiddle or pastebin are only for "backup" and demonstration purposes. That full `wp-login.php` does not need to be posted, but mention it in the Question.

Comment: Ok understand. You say that code in wp-login.php it's ok?

Comment: Yes, for testing purposes, if you add your jQuery in line `683` and modify the `input` field in line `693`, it should work. The correct way is to create a plugin and use hooks to add your custom jQuery and manipulate the DOM.  I think I understand what you're looking for, but I cannot rewrite your question to provide an answer. The thing is: the question should be useful to you but mainly to future visitors with the same problem. The question must be clear and self-contained. Please take some moments to read this site [About] page and the [help].

Comment: you want user_login field and email field to be same for wp_users table..... right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ***Just put this code in your theme's Functions.php file** ....

```
function create_new_user_login_change($user_id) {

    $new_user = get_userdata($user_id);
    $my_email = $new_user->user_email;
    wp_update_user(array('ID' => $user_id, 'user_login' => $my_email));

}

add_action('user_register', 'create_new_user_login_change');
```

> Note: We are adding a hook with 'User Registration' action, which will
>   return user_id of the the user just registered, to the connected
>   function, and that function will update 'user_login' with email of the
>   user. No need any javascript or anything else.